# BLDC motor driver identification

Tags: identification, components, brushless-dc-motor, reverse-engineering

I have one mystery fuser motor assembly from a **HP color LaserJet 9500MFP** laser copy machine.

I would like to use the BLDC motor in my own project and control it with an Arduino, but I cannot find any information about the IC or the module itself. The module is named **"RH7-1519"** and the IC **"TLS9109"**

If someone knows any documentation about this, it would be really helpful, but if not, I must reverse-engineer it completely by only trying different things.

All I know about this board is that it uses **two** wires **for ground**, **two for power** and **5 for** different **signals.** Also I don't know the voltage rating of this IC, but there appears to be a **35 volt capacitor** on the board.
I have a feeling that the copy machine would have used **24 volts** on most of the components.
At least all of the (around 10) fans were 24V...

Here is a drive [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U7i6XgEjHYg5vTqa1EFo12jv0bvaxKiT) to the images

Comment: You will have: 1) Application hardware/software. 2) Motor Driver. 3) Motor. If you want to reuse the motor driver, you need to break the connection between #1 and #2, and understand this interface. The interface may be difficult or impossible to break, it may be integrated inside an IC. Reusing only the motor will be easier.

Comment: please add the pictures directly into your post ... use the button that looks like the moon and mountains

Comment: Apparently my images were too large

Comment: @TomasAntola so crop and scale them!